# Strange ClassCastException on ADF Mobile App

Tags: oracle-adf-mobile

I use JDev 11.1.2.4
I have a custom Supplier class which is being load some items by invoking applicationScope bean method.
I am trying to transform my object to appropriate selectItems. I could obtain right object list essentially, but suddenly faced ClassCastException. Unfortunatelly, i could not find any solution on internet.
I know those classes are exactly same. (additionaly i see on debug time that package and classeses has no difference as seen)
Where is the problem?? I read on internet something about different classloaders but i couldnt reach root cause or solution.
please helpme
brgds

```
   package com.accmee.mobile.supplier;

    import com.accmee.mobile.pojo.ServiceCategory;
    import com.acme.structure.util.datalist.SimpleListSupplier;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Collection;
    import java.util.List;
    import javax.el.MethodExpression;
    import oracle.adfmf.framework.api.AdfmfJavaUtilities;
    import oracle.adfmf.javax.faces.model.SelectItem;

    public class ServiceCategorySupplier extends SimpleListSupplier
    {
        public ServiceCategorySupplier(boolean blankItemApplied)
        {
            super(blankItemApplied);
        }

        public ServiceCategorySupplier()
        {
            super();
        }

        public void loadList()
        {
            try
            {
                MethodExpression me = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getMethodExpression("#{applicationScope.loginBean.loadCategories}", List.class, new Class[] { }); /* this applicationScope bean method loads through webservice consume via JavaAPI, and works properly returns list with elements**/
                List categories = (List)me.invoke(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getAdfELContext(), new Object[] { });
                itemList.addAll(getConvertedToSelectItemList(categories, true)); // here passes parameter into method which faced exception
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public String getListName()
        {
            return "categories";
        }

        public static Collection getConvertedToSelectItemList(List list, boolean blankItemApplied)
        {
            Collection convertedCollection = new ArrayList();
            SelectItem selectItem = null;

            if (blankItemApplied)
            {
                selectItem = new SelectItem();
                convertedCollection.add(selectItem);
            }
            for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
            {
                ServiceCategory superEntity  = (ServiceCategory)list.get(i); // here is the ClassCastException, this line throws exception
                selectItem = getConvertedToSelectItem(superEntity);
                convertedCollection.add(selectItem);
            }
            return convertedCollection;
        }


        public static SelectItem getConvertedToSelectItem(ServiceCategory superEntity)
        {
            SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();
            selectItem.setLabel(superEntity.getName());
            selectItem.setValue(superEntity);
            return selectItem;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please consider those link
http://tinypic.com/r/2rrquxs/5
http://tinypic.com/r/10rp93b/5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to change my approach. So, i changed returnType of loadCategories method to GenericType instead of my custom class.
Then it worked like that.

```
public class ServiceCategorySupplier extends SimpleListSupplier
{
    public ServiceCategorySupplier(boolean blankItemApplied)
    {
        super(blankItemApplied);
    }


    public ServiceCategorySupplier()
    {
        super();
    }


    public void loadList()
    {
        try
        {
            MethodExpression me = AdfmfJavaUtilities.getMethodExpression("#{applicationScope.loginBean.loadCategories}", List.class, new Class[] { });
            List categories = (List)me.invoke(AdfmfJavaUtilities.getAdfELContext(), new Object[] { });
            list.addAll(categories);
            loadItemList();
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new AdfException(e.getMessage(), AdfException.ERROR);
        }
    }


    public void loadItemList()
    {
        SelectItem selectItem = null;

        itemList=new SelectItem[list.size()];
        ServiceCategory serviceCategory=null;
        for(int i=0;i<list.size();i++)
        {
            GenericType serviceCategoryType  = (GenericType)list.get(i);
            serviceCategory = (ServiceCategory)GenericTypeBeanSerializationHelper.fromGenericType(ServiceCategory.class, serviceCategoryType);
            selectItem = getConvertedToSelectItem(serviceCategory);
            itemList[i]=selectItem;
        }
    }


    public static SelectItem getConvertedToSelectItem(ServiceCategory superEntity)
    {
        SelectItem selectItem = new SelectItem();


        selectItem.setLabel(superEntity.getName());
        selectItem.setValue(superEntity.getId());


        return selectItem;
    }


    public String getListName()
    {
        return "categories";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The same class loaded by two different classloaders is considered at runtime as two different classes. Probably that's what's happening to you.

Watch this page: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-dyn0429/

Comment: Thx, but still i don't understand how can i make them loaded by same classLoader to solve my problem. Have you got an idea?

Comment: I don't know the context of your problem, so I'll try to explain it to you in the context of a web application: To run a web server (like Tomcat) you need to execute a JVM that has it's own classloader that loads classes from the system classpath. At the same time, the Tomcat has it's own classloader that loads classes from the tomcat lib folder. And each web app deployed on Tomcat has it's own classloader that loads classses from it's WEB-INF/classes or WEB-INF/lib folder. If you happened to put the same jar on two of these three paths, you could have a problem like the one you're describing.